Trouble with deploy when edit anything on mobile
currently I was given a task to find the source of the problem of deploying mobile app.
The problem is, when trying to fix anything, even the slightest fix like edit picture. The team has to download the whole app package, unzip, edit it and push the whole package back again.
What could cause this problem? and how would you guys fix it?
What I current know is that The company didn't use public cloud to store code due to policy.
I worked on an different department and has no access to code or infrastructure.
But I think of that they has to "zip" the package, so they have to download them instead of pushing the change.
